# Poisson Distribution with multiple x

Tags: excel, excel-formula, poisson

I know how to use Poisson Distribution when x had multiple possibilities. Let's say that I want to know the chance of a game ending 0-0. F14 and J14 are the changes for the home and away team to score a goal.

```
=POISSON.DIST(0;$F$14; FALSE) *POISSON.DIST(0;$J$14; FALSE)
```

If I want it for another score I change the 0 value. This is all fine.

But let's say that I want the chance of the match ending in a draw and let's stay realistic so we go to max draw result of 5-5.

I can of course do this calculation over 5 lines and add all the % up but what if I want to do it in one cell.

```
=POISSON.DIST(0;$F$14; FALSE) *POISSON.DIST(0;$J$14; FALSE)+=POISSON.DIST(1;$F$14; FALSE) *POISSON.DIST(1;$J$14; FALSE)+=POISSON.DIST(2;$F$14; FALSE) *POISSON.DIST(2;$J$14; FALSE)+=POISSON.DIST(3;$F$14; FALSE) *POISSON.DIST(3;$J$14; FALSE)+=POISSON.DIST(4;$F$14; FALSE) *POISSON.DIST(4;$J$14; FALSE)+=POISSON.DIST(5;$F$14; FALSE) *POISSON.DIST(5;$J$14; FALSE)
```

This will give me of course a combined total of the draw %. But this can't be the correct way of doing this. Anyone any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be a sumproduct like this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(POISSON.DIST(ROW(1:5)-1,$F$14,FALSE),POISSON.DIST(ROW(1:5)-1,$J$14,FALSE))
```

(in O365 you can do it a bit more tidily using Sequence)

I tried it guessing the chance of a home goal as .5 and an away goal as .4 and got a result of .49 for a draw of any sort up to 5-5.

I believe the formula for a home win should be

```
=SUM(MMULT(POISSON.DIST(ROW(1:5)-1,$F$14,FALSE),POISSON.DIST(TRANSPOSE(ROW(1:5))-1,$J$14,FALSE))*(ROW(1:5)>TRANSPOSE(ROW(1:5))))
```

entered as an array formula, which works out to .29 using the same assumptions as before. You can get the chance of an away win just by swapping F14 and J14 and it worked out to be .22. The probabilities added up do approach one which is OK because we stopped at 5.

Comment: This is spot on! Thank you very much.

Any idea how I can get all the home wins up to 5 goals?

1 0
2 0
2 1
3 0
3 1
3 2
4 0
4 1
4 2
4 3
5 0
5 1
5 2
5 3
5 4

Comment: That's a bit more complicated, but I will add what I think it should be to my answer.

Comment: BTW my guesses seem to be quite a bit off with reality - in the English premier league for example, results are heavily weighted towards a home win and away from a draw https://help.smarkets.com/hc/en-gb/articles/115000647291-Why-you-should-consider-home-advantage-for-football-trading except for Manchester United.

Comment: I know, I just want to do a calculation :-)