# how to do a poisson distribution on excel for queuing model?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, queue, poisson

Is there any function on excel that allows a Poisson distribution for interarrival rates that fits in to a time series? Any help here will be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: There is a post on poisson distribution ; but not sure if it works on time series. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65597200/poisson-distribution-with-multiple-x

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Poisson arrival process, then the inter-arrival times have an exponential distribution with the same rate as the Poisson. An exponential with rate λ can be generated using the formula -ln(1-U)/λ, where U is a uniform(0,1) random variable. Add the result to the prior arrival time to generate the next arrival time. Since the exponential distribution is “memoryless”, you can start with an initial time of 0.